# use/need of Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have searched in this forum for the questions and have found good resources. I have written the following code myself to understand the concept of reflection.

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        MyClass1 mc1 = new MyClass1();
        Type t = mc1.GetType();
        MethodInfo mInfo = t.GetMethod("method1");
        object[] o=new object[]{2};
        Console.WriteLine(mInfo.Invoke(mc1, o));
        NameSpace2.Class1 c1 = new NameSpace2.Class1();
        Type t2 = c1.GetType();
        MethodInfo[] mI2 = t2.GetMethods();
        object[] o2 = new object[] {2,3};
        foreach (MethodInfo m in mI2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }

        object x = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
        Console.Read();

    }
```

I understand that with reflection, I will be able to get info about type, public methods, properties of an object at runtime and will also be able to create an object of that type. But my point is, unless and until I know what are the parameters the methods need as inputs, I will not be able to implement any method and those informations are only available at runtime. So, what is the importance of reflection, is it just about the information about an object?

Comment: E.g. you could read the string "method1" from a file?

Comment: ORM and databinding are nice examples of the beautiness of reflection.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-use-of-reflection-in-net-c-sharp-code-are-recommended

Comment: Have you ever wondered how is VisualStudio's Properties Window implemented?? I don't think there's a monkey typing an editor window for each object they add! --I mean no disrespect, just an illustrative joke :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need reflection, then your needs cannot be solved at compile-time but at run-time.

- Let's say you are making a cool application that needs to be modular, you let developers write plugins for your application.
  You can't compile the app for every plugin that might ever be created. Then you need to load, introspect and invoke the plugin's objects with reflection.
- Lets say you are making a middleware for a banking application, this middleware is in charge of dealing with database connections and executing some business logic with that data. You can code and compile your middleware for every single database available. Or you can code once, and just activate and use the correct database driver at run-time.
- What if you want to dynamically get a WebService's WSDL, generate a proxy and use the web service inmediately after he proxy has been compiled, and loaded into memory? Can't think of a way to do this at compile time.
- Even better, what if you generate code with CodeDOM, compile, load the compiled assembly and use the objects that you just compiled?

Some day you will need to use reflection. I hope so...

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the answer of *Adrian Salazar* i have some more examples which i faced the last years:

- **Automated wrapper generation.** I wrote a cross-plattform framework which uses OpenGL/OpenAL, to keep it simple i used delegates which are initialized after the devices are available. On iOS i need to declare every method as extern method with a dll-import attribute. OpenGL/OpenAL have both a lot of methods so i just compiled the delegates, wrote a program which writes me a *.cs file which declares all of theese methods. Right now this safes me around one Week of painfull work of keeping this wrappers up-to-date.
- **Proxy generation.** I wrote once a application which must be able to handle flash objects and display their properties in a PropertyInspector and call methods of the objects, to be able to do this, i wrote a IL-generator and used the reflection to reflect over the properties and invoke the methods.
- The most common sample should be: **Load and save data.** This task is mostly done by using reflection. I wrote a xml-reader/writer in the middle of 2012 which allows to initialize objects like you do in XAML, and save this objects into XML again. Object initialization and writing them back into XML again is a task which would cause a lot of work if you are not using reflection.

As you can see there are a lot of examples which prove that the reflection is really useful. I used reflection so many times in the last 8 years i can't even count the number of usages.

Answer (score 0):

To speak to your implied question.

> But my point is, unless and until I know what are the parameters the methods need as inputs, I will not be able to implement any method and those informations are only available at runtime.

How about we take a simple example. I want to instantiate a method on a class that requires parameters, and I'm going to be the facilitator (i.e. I will create the class and launch the method, but I know nothing about it).

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }

    public void FooMethod(string parm) { }
}

public class Facilitator
{
    public void RaiseAction(string type, string action, params object[] parm)
    {
        var o = Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", type);
        var methodInfo = o.GetType().GetMethod(action);
        if (methodInfo == null) { return; }
        methodInfo.Invoke(o, parm);
    }
}
```

Now, in the above example, I just passed parameters to a method on an object I knew nothing about.

Now, let's examine some of the other things that are possible with Reflection. Let's imagine for a moment that I need to get at a `private` member - albeit generally a bad idea - I can if necessary and I do sometimes for debugging ***and*** for hacking. Haven't you ever wanted a flag you couldn't get to at runtime to help you make a decision? You saw the flag in the debugger but it's buried in the object hierarchy ***and*** it's `private` to boot! What's worse? Microsoft said they are going to expose it somehow in a subsequent release but you need to get out the door right now and you need this flag! Or maybe you need this method!

Consider this example (where `o` is some object you need something from that's private):

```
var propertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperty("SomePublicProperty");
if (propertyInfo == null) { return; }
var myFirstPrivateMember = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetField("_somePrivateField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Uh oh, we just got our first `private` member - and a field no less!

Reflection is dear to my heart because I've built numerous applications that are completely dynamic, from the database all the way to the UX. When you build applications like that you don't know a lot about anything - you didn't configure it - but because of the flexibility of reflection you can `Invoke` and `Get` anything you want or need to get the job done.

Just like anything else, these are ***very*** simple examples of Reflection, but hopefully you get a good feel for the power of Reflection and why it's useful. In most day-to-day applications where your world is very static, you probably won't ever use it, but branch out a little bit and get more dynamic, and you'll need it.