# Refactoring foreach loop with several of if-else statements

Tags: c#

I've got this method where I'm inspecting several times if some field of `SPListItem` is `null` and if it is then write default value for that property. Is there any way that I can reduce this code? Thank you

```
public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)
{           
    List<Models.EmployeeInfo> listEmployeeInfo = new List<Models.EmployeeInfo>();

    foreach (SPListItem item in splic)
    {               
        var employeeInfo = new Models.EmployeeInfo();

        if (item["EmployeeName"] == null)
        {
            employeeInfo.EmployeeName = "";
        }
        else
        {
            employeeInfo.EmployeeName = item["EmployeeName"].ToString();
        }

        if (item["Position"] == null)
        {
            employeeInfo.Position = "";
        }
        else
        {
            employeeInfo.Position = item["Position"].ToString();
        }

        if (item["Office"] == null)
        {
            employeeInfo.Office = "";
        }
        else
        {
            employeeInfo.Office = item["Office"].ToString();
        }

        if (item["IsPublic"] == null)
        {
            employeeInfo.IsPublic = true;
        }
        else
        {
            employeeInfo.IsPublic = Convert.ToBoolean("IsPublic"); 
        }

        listEmployeeInfo.Add(employeeInfo);
    }

    return listEmployeeInfo;                                           
}
```

Comment: I think that you should try to use [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) service for that

Comment: Is that last one supposed to be `Convert.ToBoolean(item["IsPublic"])`? It doesnt match all the others

Comment: What's the code for SPList?

Comment: what about put those checking and setting default value into your model setter. It's cleaner in my opinion

Comment: @HankMooody: If you are indeed going with the *Reflection approach* (indicated by your accepted answer), this [link about Reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-net-recommended) would be useful.

Comment: @HankMooody: Also see [How costly is .NET reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458/how-costly-is-net-reflection)

Comment: yeah, I see now that reflection is bad practice when there are some nested loops.Thank you .I'll find a better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some reflection to set the property.
Then you can loop over a list of all the propertynames and set them.
( This way when a property gets added to the model, all you need to do is add it to the list of strings )

```
public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)
{
    var listEmployeeInfo = new List<Models.EmployeeInfo>();
    var propertyNames = new List<string>(){"EmployeeName","Position","Office","IsPublic"}

    foreach (SPListItem item in splic)
    {
        var employeeInfo = new Models.EmployeeInfo(); 

        foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
        {  
            string newData = "";
            if (item[propertyName] != null)
            {
                newData = item[propertyName];
            }
            employeeInfo.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(employeeInfo, newData, null); 
        }

        listEmployeeInfo.Add(employeeInfo);
    }
    return listEmployeeInfo;
}
```

Comment: This is really interesting approach and I want to use it, but I'm not familiar with Reflections , please explain me what should I do , because I can't use GetProperty extension method , error says that my class doesn't contain a definition for GetProperty extension method.
Thank you.

Comment: Forgot to add the GetType(). You shouldn't get this error anymore now, i've changed my answer.

Comment: I've figure that out , thank you .Now I'm having other error, at that line, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Found the bug.Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to something like:

```
public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)
{

  var listEmployeeInfo = new List<Models.EmployeeInfo>();
  foreach (SPListItem item in splic)
  {               
    var employeeInfo = new Models.EmployeeInfo();

    employeeInfo.EmployeeName = item["EmployeeName"] == null ? "" : item["EmployeeName"].ToString();

    employeeInfo.Position = item["Position"] == null ? "" : item["Position"].ToString();
    employeeInfo.Office = item["Office"] == null ? "" : item["Office"].ToString();

    employeeInfo.IsPublic = item["IsPublic"] == null || Convert.ToBoolean("IsPublic");

    listEmployeeInfo.Add(employeeInfo);
  }

  return listEmployeeInfo;
}
```

Comment: I think the point was to avoid the repetition, rather than just shorten the code with ternary operators

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring the common logic into a function.

```
employeeInfo.EmployeeName = ConditionalToString(item, "EmployeeName");
employeeInfo.Position = ConditionalToString(item, "Position");
employeeInfo.Office = ConditionalToString(item, "Office");
employeeInfo.IsPublic = item[attrName] == null ? false : Convert.ToBoolean("IsPublic");

string ConditionalToString(SPListItem item, string attrName)
{
    return (item[attrName] == null ? "" : item[attrName].ToString());
}
```

The [null coalesce operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) won't work since item[attrName] and "" are different types, so something like this wouldn't work: `(item[attrName] ?? "").ToString()` (would `dynamic` be helpful in this case? I don't use it often).

[TLJ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184602/refactoring-foreach-loop-with-several-of-if-else-statements/34184836#comment56115835_34184602) is an alternative solution for where this logic can take place (although you will still have the same repetition there).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer given here which uses ternary operator. Strangely I was studying this same thing yesterday. You can and should use ternary operator here instead of *if - else*.

**Advantages?**

- For one, it'll make the code shorter for you to see in one glance.
- The bigger advantage is this... your current code is statement based. So what you are doing is that *you are testing a condition and executing statements as a side-effect of that condition*. *But when using ternary operator you are **using expression to compute results*** (which is exactly what you are trying to do - you are trying to generate your `employeeInfo` object to put in a list).
- In your current design for each attribute you have 2 places where its value is assigned (the *if* block and the *else* block). When using ternary operator, the values are being assigned at one place only.

Further, you can refactor the `employeeInfo` object creation to another method and keep the current method cleaner (like shown below):

```
public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)
{
    var listEmployeeInfo = new List<Models.EmployeeInfo>();
    foreach (SPListItem splicItem in splic)
    {               
      listEmployeeInfo.Add(CreateEmployeeInfoFromItem(splicItem));
    }
    return listEmployeeInfo;
}

private static Models.EmployeeInfo CreateEmployeeInfoFromItem(SPListItem item)
{
    var employeeInfo = new Models.EmployeeInfo();
    employeeInfo.EmployeeName = item["EmployeeName"] == null ? "" : item["EmployeeName"].ToString();
    employeeInfo.Position = item["Position"] == null ? "" : item["Position"].ToString();
    employeeInfo.Office = item["Office"] == null ? "" : item["Office"].ToString();
    employeeInfo.IsPublic = item["IsPublic"] == null || Convert.ToBoolean("IsPublic");
    return employeeInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating a mapping object that has the sole responsibility of creating an EmployeeInfo instance from a given instance of SPListItem. In this mapping object you would have your validation criteria/setting criteria, and then any time you have this need come up you have a nice mapping object ready to do the job.

```
public class SPListItemToEmployeeInfoMapper
{
    public static Models.EmployeeInfo Map(SpListItem item);
    { //your logic here to create the employeeinfo from SpListItem }
}
```

Then your caller:

```
public List<Models.EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfo(SPListItemCollection splic)
{
   var listEmployeeInfo = new List<Models.EmployeeInfo>();
   foreach (SPListItem splicItem in splic)
   {               
      listEmployeeInfo.Add(SPListItemToEmployeeInfoMapper.Map(splicItem));
   }
   return listEmployeeInfo;
}
```