# Usage and Purpose of Reflection in C# in real-time scenarios

Tags: c#

I want to find out about the purpose of Reflection in C#. I've gone through various articles about it on various sites including 'Stack Overflow', but still I couldn't find an comprehensive answer describing Reflection. It will be very helpful to me if someone could provide answer explaining real-time scenarios where they had come across situations where using Reflection was a necessity.

Comment: All ORMs need a way to find out how object properties are named so they can generate the appropriate SQL statements.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih that's not accurate. That's only 10% of the uses or Reflection

Comment: Did you lookup the wiki of reflection, section 'uses'?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the use of reflection in .NET recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-net-recommended)

Comment: All serializers use reflection to find the properties and data of the objects they need to serialize. Reading an attribute, like a mapping attribute or display format also requires reflection

Comment: Even one single google-search and you get a thousand explanation and you say you don´t find any? What did you search?

Comment: Have u referred this SO Question??
[Why is the use of reflection in .NET recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-net-recommended)
check might clear your doubts

Comment: Dynamically generated UIs also use reflection.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I use it for that most of the time, sure there are many more scenarios, but those were the ones that came to my mind.

Comment: Factory-classes often use reflection...

Comment: Consider reflection as a means to discover information about your or others assemblies. A very common usage may be for example supporting a third party developer plugin ecosystem.
Take a look here this may inspire you https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/791017/Reflection-Concept-and-Late-Binding-in-Csharp

Comment: Thanks for providing your answers. Actually, like I've mentioned in my question itself, I want if people could answer about it based on real-time scenarios where they've actually used themselves.

Comment: While your question is clear it doesn´t fit the rules for StackOverflow as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This is why no-one answers but vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you want to build a plugin system. You would have a minimum set of things that your application needs to know about your plugin. Lets assume the following:

- Each plugin is a dll
- Each plugin has a class called PluginStart
- PluginStart is in the namespace Plugin
- PluginStart has a property Message of type string

If you now want to load a plugin and get the Message properties value you have to do it using reflection. A simple example could be something like this:

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
Type importStartType = dll?.GetType("Plugin.pluginStart");
string message = importStartType?.GetField("Message")?.GetValue(importStartType)?.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework's Reflection API allows you to fetch Type (Assembly) information at runtime programmatically. We can also achieve the late binding by using .NET Reflection. At runtime, Reflection mechanism uses the PE file to read the information about the assembly. Reflection enables you to use code that was not available at compile time. .NET Reflection allows application to collect information about itself and also manipulate on itself. It can be used effectively to find all the types in an assembly and/or dynamically invoke methods in an assembly. This includes information about the type, properties, methods and events of an object. With reflection we can dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the type from an existing object and invoke its methods or access its fields and properties. We can also access attribute information using reflection.

This will help you.

[Why is the use of reflection in .NET recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-net-recommended)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/keesari_anjaiah/reflection-in-net/