# How to invoke method in parent class from child class using reflection?

Tags: c#

I create child objects (Customer, Product, ...) and invoke method ApplyChange in parent class (AggregateRoot), from that method I would like to call method Apply in child class for passed event. Is it possible using reflection or I should change something?

```
public abstract class AggregateRoot
{
    public void ApplyChange(IEvent @event)
    {
        Apply(@event); // how to call this method?
    }
}


public class Customer : AggregateRoot
{    
    private void Apply(CustomerCreatedEvent e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CustomerCreatedEvent");
    }
}

public class Product : AggregateRoot
{
    private void Apply(ProductCreatedEvent e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ProductCreatedEvent");
    }
}

public interface IEvent
{
}

public class CustomerCreatedEvent : IEvent
{
}

public class ProductCreatedEvent : IEvent
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.ApplyChange(new CustomerCreatedEvent());

        Product product = new Product();
        product.ApplyChange(new ProductCreatedEvent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the methods from private to protected perhaps?

Comment: The architecture you are trying to achieve does not seem to require any reflection at all, Reflection breaks out of the object oriented paradigm. It's like the ability to throw away OOP at a moments notice and unleash a spaghetti monster of code that has no rules and can access and modify the process running next to it, (not really, it's hyperbole). I think this article outlines very well [when to use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-net-recommended). Reflection is not a substitute for a well constructed inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible using reflection or I should change something?

I focused for now on the non-reflection, as IMO reflection should be the last resort here.

### Option 1: abstract method

You could make  `Apply` an abstract method en then you could call it from `AggregateRoot`.

e.g.

```cs
using System;


public abstract class AggregateRoot
{
    public void ApplyChange(IEvent @event)
    {
        Apply(@event); // how to call this method?
    }

    protected abstract void Apply(IEvent e);
}

public class Customer : AggregateRoot
{
    protected override void Apply(IEvent e)
    {
        if (e is CustomerCreatedEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CustomerCreatedEvent");
        }
    }
}

public class Product : AggregateRoot
{
    protected override void Apply(IEvent e)
    {
        if (e is ProductCreatedEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ProductCreatedEvent");
        }
    }
}

public interface IEvent
{
}

public class CustomerCreatedEvent : IEvent
{
}

public class ProductCreatedEvent : IEvent
{
}
```

But please note, it has it downsides as:

- methods needs to non-private
- the should have the same parameter type for Apply. (`IEvent` parameter) - so I've added the type check inside the Apply methods.

### Option 2: abstract method and generic AggregateRoot

Another option is to make AggregateRoot generic for the type IEvent, e.g. something like this.

```
using System;


public abstract class AggregateRoot<TEvent>
where TEvent : IEvent
{
    public void ApplyChange(TEvent @event)
    {
        Apply(@event); // how to call this method?
    }

    protected abstract void Apply(TEvent e);
}

public class Customer : AggregateRoot<CustomerCreatedEvent>
{
    protected override void Apply(CustomerCreatedEvent e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CustomerCreatedEvent");

    }
}

public class Product : AggregateRoot<ProductCreatedEvent>
{
    protected override void Apply(ProductCreatedEvent e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ProductCreatedEvent");
    }

}

public interface IEvent
{
}

public class CustomerCreatedEvent : IEvent
{
}

public class ProductCreatedEvent : IEvent
{
}
```

Note I've changed also ApplyChange in this case.

If those things won't solve your problem, please elaborate what you are trying to archive, otherwise this will be a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)